# Problems with Scope in Angular Js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope

I'm having some problems with scope in Angular.

My code is:

```
angular.module('main', [])
.controller('controller-div', function($scope) {

    var pathArray = window.location.pathname.split('/');
    var levelLocation = pathArray[2];
    console.log("location: " + levelLocation);

    $.get("/api/summoner/" + levelLocation, 
        function(data) {
            var newData = JSON.parse(data);
            console.log(newData);
            $scope.summoner = "Text to test scope";
            console.log($scope.summoner);
        });
    }
);
```

and my front end uses `{{summoner}}` to display the data.

The Ajax call and all the console logs work fine, however no data appears on the page. If I set `$scope.summoner` outside of the `$.get` call the "Text to test scope" appears perfectly fine, but I can't access the data as I'm out of the scope of the Get call(?).

I tried setting the callback data to a pre-instantiated variable, and used that afterwards yet it still didn't work. I have also tried:

```
$.get("/api/summoner/" + levelLocation, 
    (function (s) {
        return function(data) {
            var newData = JSON.parse(data);
            console.log(newData);
            s.summoner = "hjkhdkjhe";
            console.log(s.summoner);
        }
    })($scope));
```

but to no avail.

Any help would be appreciated!

EDIT: Question has been solved but for future reference, here's my HTML.

```
<body ng-app="main">
    <div ng-controller="controller-div">
        <h1>Hello University World!</h1>
            The ID is {{summoner}}
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Please post your HTML so we even have chance to help. Even better: create a fiddle or JSBin project from it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're doing asynchronous calls to a backend you should be using AngularJS's [$http service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) and [promise api](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q).

You're using jQuery's $.get to call the backend, so AngularJS doesn't know when the call is done so it can then update the scope with the new value.

Comment: Perfect! I changed it to $http, and it worked perfectly (as far as I know) I'm not too sure on the $q promise, but is that a part of the same thing? I'll have a read up on it later :) Thanks again!

Comment: $http uses the same interface as $q, but $q can be used for anything (not just network requests) :-)

Comment: Oh cool, sounds good. Cheers for your help :) Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
$http.get("/api/summoner/" + levelLocation).success(function(data) {
            var newData = data; // data doesn't need parse
            $scope.summoner = "Text to test scope";
        });
```

**Don't forget:**

Include **$http** in your controller

Comment: I did forget to include the $http actually, got it fixed but thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

You have to call $scope.$apply() after response is came.
For example:

```
var pathArray = window.location.pathname.split('/');
var levelLocation = pathArray[2];
console.log("location: " + levelLocation);

$.get("/api/summoner/" + levelLocation, 
    function(data) {
        var newData = JSON.parse(data);
        console.log(newData);
        $scope.summoner = "Text to test scope";
        console.log($scope.summoner);
        $scope.$apply(); 
    });
}
```

);

Comment: Using `$scope.$apply()` as a "catch all" when something doesn't work is bad practice to get into. OP should be using the `$http` service to get around having to do this because angular will do it for him.

Comment: Agree with you, but in such "code-context" it is ok :)

Answer (score 0):

glcheetham is correct, but it doesn't fully answer the question. The $scope inside your $.Get is different from the $scope where {{summoner}} is. That's why you can set it outside your $.Get block, but not inside. It's confusing because you're using the same name ($scope) to reference two different things.

You are experiencing "Scope Soup" which I read about from Josh Carroll [here](http://www.technofattie.com/2014/03/21/five-guidelines-for-avoiding-scope-soup-in-angular.html).

per item #3 in the article, here is how I would write it. Notice there are no references to $scope.

```
angular.module('main', []);
.controller('controller-div', function() {
_this = this; //_this will be available everywhere, even inside your promise block.
var pathArray = window.location.pathname.split('/');
var levelLocation = pathArray[2];
console.log("location: " + levelLocation);

$.http.post("/api/summoner/" + levelLocation).then(
//SUCCESS Callback        
function(data){
        var newData = JSON.parse(data);
        console.log(data);
        //scope inside promise block
        this.summoner = "Text to test scope";
        console.log(this.summoner);
        //scope where you want to change displayed data
        _this.summoner = newData;
        console.log(_this.summoner);
    });
}
);
```

Now in your html, use the "controller-as"syntax and pre-pend your summoner with ctrl.

```
<body ng-app="main">
    <div ng-controller="controller-div as ctrl">
    <h1>Hello University World!</h1>
        The ID is {{ctrl.summoner}}
    </div>
</body>
```